# Почему Firebase и Google Play Console выдают разную статистику?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

Абсолютно не совпадают данные ни по странам, ни по количеству установок.

Comment: подвисание статистики, может быть кеширование

Comment: в гугл консоли идет отставание по статистике на пару дней, если вы попытаетесь запросить статистику из консоли допустим за последние 7 дней, то вы убедитесь по датам, что там всегда последних суток-двое пока нет. в то время как firebase показывает всю статистику в рантайме